# Multi-level approvals

Tags: approval-process

I am trying to create multi-level approvals and having trouble getting 2nd and 3rd approval (not sure if this is possible or not?)

Scenario:

I need 3 levels of approval for orders.

- Anything under £100 doesn't need approval.
- £100 - £10k - needs to be approved by Person X
- £10k - £25k - needs to be approved by Person X, and then Person Y.
- £25k+ - needs to be approved by Person X, Person Y and then Person Z.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue you are facing in 2nd and 3rd approvals?

Answer (score 0):

You could create 3 approval processes for each one of those conditions.

For 2nd and 3rd approval processes, add respective approvers and choose "Require UNANIMOUS approval from all selected approvers."

[image: Approval Step]